# How to use camera from a fragment and display captured image in an imageview on the same fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to display a captured image in my fragment but it is not showing, e.g. though the callback code in the fragment appears to be running.

Here's my Activity -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    // Views and Context
    private View nav_header_view;
    private Context context;

    // Widgets
    private TextView tvCompanyName, tvCompanyEmail, tvName;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;

    // Data
    private FragmentManager manager;
    private int selectNavId;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String uuId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        setTitle("Home");
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                switch (selectNavId) {

                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        openSearchFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        displayTabForHomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_daily_sales:
                        openDailySalesFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_store:
                        openCompanyFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_purchase:
                        openOrderedFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_account:
                        openAccountFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        logoutSession();
                }
            }

        };

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        initializeUI();
        checkUserSession();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        nav_header_view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        tvName = (TextView) nav_header_view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvCompanyName = (TextView) nav_header_view.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);
        tvCompanyEmail = (TextView) nav_header_view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        imageView = (ImageView) nav_header_view.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_picture);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main);

            if (f instanceof DailySalesFragment) {
                closeSession();
            } else {
//                openHomeFragment();
                openDailySalesFragment();
            }

        }
    }

    private void checkUserSession() {
        String authToken = UserSession.getToken(this);

        if (authToken.length() <= 0 && UserAccount.checkUserCount(context) > 0) {
            openUserActivity();
        } else if (authToken.length() <= 0) {
            Intent login_intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(login_intent);
            this.finish();
        } else {
            updateNavName(context);
            openDailySalesFragment();
        }
    }

    public void updateNavName(Context context) {
        tvName.setText(UserSession.getFirstName(context) + " " + UserSession.getLastName(context));
        tvCompanyName.setText(UserSession.getCompany(this));
        tvCompanyEmail.setText(UserSession.getEmployeeEmail(this));
        showProfilePic();
    }

    public void showProfilePic() {
//        if (UserSession.getProfilePicture(context).contains("media")) {
//            RequestOptions myOption = new RequestOptions().circleCrop();
//            Glide.with(context).load(UserSession.getProfilePicture(context)).apply(myOption).into(imageView);
//        }
    }

    private void logoutSession() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        UserSession.clearSession(context);
                        removeAllInCart();
                        checkUserSession();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        PopUpProvider.buildConfirmationDialog(context, dialogClickListener, "Confirm logout", "Are you sure you want to log out?");
    }

    private void closeSession() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        PopUpProvider.buildConfirmationDialog(context, dialogClickListener, "Are you sure you want to close application?", null);
    }

    private void removeAllInCart() {
        Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
        checkout.deleteAll(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        selectNavId = id;

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void refreshFragment() {
        try {
            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main);

            if (f instanceof CompanyFragment) {
                openCompanyFragment();
            } else if (f instanceof OrderedFragment) {
                openOrderedFragment();
            } else if (f instanceof AccountFragment) {
                openAccountFragment();
            } else {
//                openHomeFragment();
                openDailySalesFragment();
            }


        } catch (Exception err) {
            Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
        }
    }

    private void openUserActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(context, UserAccountActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    private void openHomeFragment(String uuid) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("uuid", uuid);

        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, homeFragment, homeFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }

    private void openOrderedFragment() {
        setTitle("My Purchases");
        OrderedFragment orderedFragment = new OrderedFragment();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, orderedFragment, orderedFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }

    private void openAccountFragment() {
        setTitle("Account");
        AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, accountFragment, "ACCOUNT_TAG").commit();

    }

    private void openCompanyFragment() {
        setTitle("Store");
        CompanyFragment companyFragment = new CompanyFragment();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, companyFragment, companyFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }

    private void openDailySalesFragment() {
        setTitle("Daily Sales");
        DailySalesFragment dailySalesFragment = new DailySalesFragment();
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, dailySalesFragment, dailySalesFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }

    private void openSearchFragment() {
        setTitle("Select Category");
        replaceFragment(SearchFragment.class, null);
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Class fragmentClass, Bundle bundle) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
    }

    // Online functions
    public void fetchCategory() {
        try {
            HttpClientProvider.get(context, "read_category/", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
                    super.onPreProcessResponse(instance, response);

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        tabLayout.removeAllTabs();

                        categoryArrayList = new Gson().fromJson(response.getJSONArray("records").toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Category>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        Category category = new Category();
                        category.setName("All");
                        categoryArrayList.add(0, category);

                        for (Category inventory : categoryArrayList) {
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(inventory.getName()));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception err) {
                        Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                    Toasty.error(context, "Can't Connect to Server").show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    Toasty.error(context, responseString).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                    super.onRetry(retryNo);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception err) {
            Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
        }
    }

    public void displayTabForHomeFragment() {
        fetchCategory();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if (position > 0) {
                        uuId = categoryArrayList.get(position).getUuId();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("uuid", uuId);
                        openHomeFragment(uuId);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        openHomeFragment("");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here's my Fragment -

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    // View and Context
    private View view;
    private Context context;

    // Widget
    private EditText tvFirstName, tvLastName, tvCode, tvEmail, tvEmployeeId;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Button btnUpdate, btnUpload;
    private boolean updateSuccess = false;

    //Data
    private ArrayList<UserAccount> userAccountArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    // Handles Interface and Initialization Functions
    // Parameters - Default
    // Return - View mag display sa layout

    public AccountFragment(){
        super();
    }


    public static AccountFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("ARG_SECTION_NUMBER", sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        context = getContext();
        initializeUI();
    }

    // Initialize component from a layout file
    private void initializeUI() {
        tvFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
        tvLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_lastname);
        tvCode = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_code);
        tvEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tvEmployeeId = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_employee_id);
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_User);
        btnUpdate = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
        btnUpload = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_UploadImage);

        ((MainActivity) context).tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getUserProfile();

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateUserProfile();
            }
        });

//        showProfilePic();

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });

    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(camIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

    private void showProfilePic() {
        if (UserSession.getProfilePicture(context).contains("media")) {
            RequestOptions myOption = new RequestOptions().circleCrop();
            Glide.with(context).load(UserSession.getProfilePicture(context)).apply(myOption).into(imageView);
        }
    }

    private void displayEmployeeDetails() {

        tvFirstName.setText(UserSession.getFirstName(getContext()));
        tvLastName.setText(UserSession.getLastName(getContext()));
        tvCode.setText(UserSession.getEmployeeCode(getContext()));
        tvEmail.setText(UserSession.getEmployeeEmail(getContext()));
        tvEmployeeId.setText(UserSession.getYpoEmployeeId(getContext()));
//        showProfilePic();
    }

    public void getUserProfile() {
        try {

            HttpClientProvider.get(context, "customer_profile/", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
                    progressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPreProcessResponse(ResponseHandlerInterface instance, HttpResponse response) {
                    super.onPreProcessResponse(instance, response);

                }


                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        UserSession session = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<UserSession>() {
                        }.getType());
                        session.saveUserSession2(context);
                        if (session.saveUserSession2(context)) {
                            displayEmployeeDetails();
                            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateNavName(context);
                        }

                        if (updateSuccess) {

                            Toasty.success(context, "Update success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //Update account in database
                            String searchQuery;
                            searchQuery = " WHERE e_mail LIKE '%" + UserSession.getEmployeeEmail(context) + "%' ";
                            userAccountArrayList = UserAccount.read(context, searchQuery);

                            for (UserAccount userAccount : userAccountArrayList) {
                                userAccount.setFirstName(UserSession.getFirstName(getContext()));
                                userAccount.setLastName(UserSession.getLastName(getContext()));
                                userAccount.setEmail(UserSession.getEmployeeEmail(getContext()));
                                userAccount.setToken(UserSession.getToken(getContext()));
                                userAccount.save(context);
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (Exception err) {
                        Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                    Debugger.printO("JSONObject " + throwable.toString());
                    Toasty.error(context, "Server Error").show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    Toasty.error(context, responseString).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception err) {
            Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
        }

    }

    private void updateUserProfile() {

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("first_name", tvFirstName.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("last_name", tvLastName.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("code", tvCode.getText().toString());
            jsonObject.put("ypo_employee_id", tvEmployeeId.getText().toString());

            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());

            HttpClientProvider.post(context, "customer_profile/", stringEntity, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
                    progressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

                        getUserProfile();
                        updateSuccess = true;

                    } catch (Exception err) {
                        Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                    Toasty.error(context, "Server Error").show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                    Toasty.error(context, errorResponse.toString()).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                    Toasty.error(context, responseString).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

        } catch (Exception err) {
            Toasty.error(context, err.toString()).show();
        }
    }

    //Hide item in Action bar
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        MenuItem quantityItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_quantity);
        MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        MenuItem menuRemove = menu.findItem(R.id.action_remove_all);
        menuRemove.setVisible(false);
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
        quantityItem.setVisible(false);
        searchViewItem.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Here's my Manifest -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

When I clicked the Camera intent in the fragment, the imageview in my fragment wouldn't change. I don't know why is this happening because it works perfectly fine in an activity.

Comment: Your code looks OK, upon first inspection. Is `onActivityResult()` running at all? Are you certain that the `ImageView` is visible in your `Fragment`?

Comment: @MikeM. : yes, my `onActivityResult()` in the fragment is running and my `ImageView` in the fragment is also visible.

Comment: Is `data.getExtras().get("data")` returning a valid `Bitmap`?

Comment: @MikeM. yes sir. it shows the value of bitmap and i dont know why it woudnt display any image.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure that the `ImageView` is visible? I'm not talking about the `visibility` attribute. I mean, is it actually on-screen, and not out of bounds, for some reason? Also, I notice that your `showProfilePic()` method is loading an image into `ImageView`. Are you sure that's not interfering, somehow? Maybe loading a null image, after you're setting it in `onActivityResult()`? I see that you have those calls commented out everywhere, but I'm not sure if that's the code you're currently running. You might also check `getWidth()`/`getHeight()` of `photo`, just to be sure.

Comment: @MikeM. the `showProfile()` method is not called. I commented the method call. In the code that I posted, that method is not even called.

Comment: @MikeM. I just want to display the bitmap into the imageview in the fragment after clicking OK on the camera. As you can see, i dont have a method `onActivityResult()` in the MainActivity. Is it ok? or do i really need to implement that method?

Comment: No, you don't. If `onActivityResult()` is running in the `Fragment`, then there is no issue in the `Activity`.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay, thanks. I know that this code is okay but i dont know whats the problem. hehe

Comment: I've already mentioned it twice, but how are you determining that the `ImageView` is actually visible? If you're _absolutely certain_ that it is visible, then I would suggest that you edit your question to provide a [mcve], removing all of the code not necessary to demonstrate the issue, and including the relevant layouts.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry, it's my first time posting here. This is my last resort to solve this problem by posting it here. Well anyway, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Activity.onResume ()` you end up calling `openAccountFragment ()`. This creates a new fragment and is run every time the screen becomes visible.(By the way a possibly unrelated bug is that you are not calling `newInstance()` here.)

Each time you create a new fragment, the old one is removed.

But your call back function is happening on the old fragment, which is no longer attached or therefore visible (note this ties in with [Mike's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808537/how-to-use-camera-in-a-fragment-and-display-captured-image-in-an-imageview-on-th#comment94466817_53808537))

The solution is to not replace the existing fragment with a new one if you already have the right type.

Comment: Thanks, so i should not use my `refreshFragments()` method?

Comment: You can use something similar, because you might want to refresh something, but do not create a new fragment if you already have one. If you have the right fragment already then let it stay there. There is no need to create a new `AccountFragment` if you already have one.

Comment: Nice catch, there. I was too focused on the `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. and Richard. You two are a life saver :) I just commented the `refreshFragments()` method and IT WORKED!

I can now go on with the project. SUPER THANKS GUYS :)

Comment: @Mike let's see if it solves the problem. I'm just busy cleaning up a project with a lot of these weird fragment lifecycle issues in it so this is what jumped out for me. Your comment initially made me think about layout and measure maybe not having been run.

Comment: IT SOLVED the problem guys. Thank you very much.

Comment: see the answer unable to comment long word

Answer (score 0):

override onActivityResult into MainActivity. make imageView public and access imageView into activity result method as follow.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main);

            if (f instanceof AccountFragment) {
                 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 f.imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. You really helped me with this one.